# Common string format for PInvoke using Protocol buffers / Protobuf

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, pinvoke

I have a C++ library giving me access to large datasets. I am using this in a C# application, by using PInvoke to invoke the C++ functions.

I have used protobuf to serialize a dataset in C++, pass the data as a string to C# and deserialize in C#.

C++ pseudocode

```
ReadData(..., char * &output, ...){
    Dataset data = ReadData(...);
    ProtoBufDataset protobufDataset = SerializeToProtobufStructure(data);
    string serialized = protobufDataset.SeralizeToString();

    // allocate serialized to output string
    ::CoTaskMemAlloc(output, serialized);
    return true;
}
```

C# wrapper function definition

```
[DllImport("CPLusPLusdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        internal static extern bool ReadData(
            ...
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out string output,
            ...);
```

C# pseudocode

```
string serializedData;
ReadDataFromCplusPlus(...., out serializedData, ...)
ProtobufDataset protobufDataset;
protoBufDataset.Deserialize(serializedData);
...
```

This worked, but I had issues deserializing some datasets, which I am fairly sure has to do with string encoding or lack of handling it. I added base64 encoding/decoding on both sides and that seems to work.

C++ pseudocode

```
ReadData(..., char * &output, ...){
    Dataset data = ReadData(...);
    ProtoBufDataset protobufDataset = SerializeToProtobufStructure(data);
    string serialized = protobufDataset.SeralizeToString();
    string encoded = base64_encode(serialized);

    // allocate serialized to output string
    ::CoTaskMemAlloc(output, encoded);
    return true;
}
```

C# pseudocode

```
string serializedData;
ReadDataFromCplusPlus(...., out serializedData, ...)
ProtobufDataset protobufDataset;
protoBufDataset.DeserializeInBase64(serializedData);
...
```

I am not to happy with the overhead for the base64 encoding. My question is could I achieve the same result using marshaling parameters and/or the correct data types in the Invoke function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using LPStr as Marshalling-Type, you should make sure, to use unicode strings, because System.String in C# is unicode and default character set in C++ is Multi-Byte (UCS2).

You can do this in your project settings in Visual Studio.
Make sure Character Set is set to "Use Unicode Character Set". This should solve your problems.

You could also translate the UCS2 to Unicode in C# (already on SO, but this will also mean overhead, which you can avoid by choosing Unicode in C++.